# multiple queries - Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]

Tags: node.js

I am trying to make simple dashboard with multiple sql statements. I went through lot of topics here but still not able to pass the sql response to web page. ([Multiple sql queries in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33297661/multiple-sql-queries-in-nodejs) is similar but I wanted to avoid a very long code if more statements are used)

When trying without select statement as parameter than it works but if select statement is as parameter and not defined in function than receiving

> Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object
>   Undefined]

Is this good way to do it? Could you support please, what is wrong?

This is actuall state:

```
function selectStmt(stmt) {
    return function (req, res, cb) {
        pg.connect(conString, function (err, client, next) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                client.query(stmt, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        req.package = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.rows));
                        console.log(req);
                        cb(req.package);
                        next();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}

var getDataX = selectStmt('select x from tblX');
var getDataY = selectStmt('select y from tblY');

router.get('/', getDataX(), getDataY(), function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('dbtestasync', {dataPackage1: req.package, dataPackage2: req.package});
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Do you use express.js. Can you show us your app configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're constructing your route definition incorrectly. You're executing the middleware functions as you're passing them, `getDataX()`. You need to pass in the reference to the middleware function, `getDataX`. Express will then pass to the callback function containing the `req`, `res`, and `next` arguments.

```
router.get('/', getDataX, getDataY, function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('dbtestasync', {dataPackage1: req.package, dataPackage2: req.package});
});
```